# Run Process to All file on Listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I need some lil' help here, i getting stuck with my code.
So i make audio converter flac to mp3 using ffmpeg.exe
i get the reference from this source code -> [converter](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sstqqe9ewzhgpsc/flvConvert.rar?dl=0)

when i implemented on my code, i getting error.
when i click on the "PictureBox3 / Mulai convert", the ffmpeg can't start the compression.
what's wrong with my code? FYI, im set the location for the output on the bottom of the listbox.

this my source :

```
Public Class LossLesstoLossy

Dim proc As New Process 'make it global so dat we can kill it from outside

Function startConversion()
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    Dim input As String = Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim output As String = Me.SaveFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim exepath As String = Application.StartupPath + "\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
    'Dim quality As Integer = TrackBar1.Value * 2

    Dim startinfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    Dim sr As StreamReader
    Dim cmd As String = " -i """ + input + """ -ar 22050 -qscale " & +output + """" 'ffmpeg commands -y replace

    '22050
    'quality & " -y """ 

    Dim ffmpegOutput As String

    ' all parameters required to run the process
    startinfo.FileName = exepath
    startinfo.Arguments = cmd
    startinfo.UseShellExecute = False
    startinfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    startinfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    startinfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    proc.StartInfo = startinfo
    proc.Start() ' start the process
    'Me.lblInfo.Text = "Conversion in progress... Please wait..."
    sr = proc.StandardError 'standard error is used by ffmpeg
    Me.PictureBox3.Enabled = False
    Do
        'If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then 'check if a cancellation request was made
        'Exit Function
        'End If
        ffmpegOutput = sr.ReadLine
        'Me.txtProgress.Text = ffmpegOutput
    Loop Until proc.HasExited And ffmpegOutput = Nothing Or ffmpegOutput = ""

    'Me.txtProgress.Text = "Finished !"
    'Me.lblInfo.Text = "Completed!"
    MsgBox("Completed!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    Me.PictureBox3.Enabled = True
    Return 0
End Function


Dim paths As String()
Dim filenames As String()
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "*.flac|*.flac"
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        filenames = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
        'paths = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
        For i As Integer = 0 To filenames.Length - 1
            ListBox1.Items.Add(filenames(i))

        Next
    End If

    'If
    'OpenFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = True
    'ListBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

    'End If

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click

    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)

End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    pemutarmusik.URL = ListBox1.SelectedItem

    'Label2.Text = pemutarmusik.currentMedia.getItemInfo("title")

End Sub


Private Function Directory() As Object

    Throw New NotImplementedException

End Function


Private Sub PictureBox3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Click
    If ListBox1.Text = "" Or ListBox1.Text <> OpenFileDialog1.FileName Then
        MsgBox("File Audio Tidak Tersedia untuk Di Kompresi", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Select a file")
        Exit Sub
        'ElseIf txtSave.Text = "" Or TextBox1.Text <> SaveFileDialog1.FileName Then
        'MsgBox("Select your output filename", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Select a file")
        'Exit Sub
    End If
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()


End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.Click
    AboutBox1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    bukafolder.ShowDialog()
    TextBox1.Text = bukafolder.SelectedPath
End Sub

Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub descr_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub descr1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click
    Form2.ShowDialog()
    'pemutarmusik.close()
End Sub


Private Sub mskform2(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.MouseDown
    pemutarmusik.close()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    'startConversion()
End Sub

Private Sub bukafolder_HelpRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bukafolder.HelpRequest
    'bukafolder.OverwritePrompt = True
    'bukafolder.DereferenceLinks = True
    'bukafolder.CreatePrompt = True
    'bukafolder.DefaultExt = ".flac"
    'bukafolder.Text = dlgSave.FileName
End Sub

Private Sub SaveFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles SaveFileDialog1.FileOk
    SaveFileDialog1.OverwritePrompt = True
    SaveFileDialog1.DereferenceLinks = True
    SaveFileDialog1.CreatePrompt = True
    SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".mp3"
    TextBox1.Text = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
End Sub

Private Sub LossLesstoLossy_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


End Sub

Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Enter

End Sub

End Class
```

hope you will help me, i really lazy with this problem :(
sorry for lot of command on my source code :D and i hope you understand my problem.
thank you
if you want fast compile the code, i give the link here -> [Audio Converter](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8vq5ulw42nehr4a/Audio%20Converter.rar?dl=0)

thank you

Comment: Have you tried to execute the command line by hand to see if the command actually works?

Comment: What's the error you are getting? You should print out the command line and test it, you'll notice the output isn't in quotes. Also, you are mixing & and +, turn option strict on

Comment: @Nitram i tried on another project (flvconvert) and its work. but when i put on my project (audioconverter) nothing happen. the process cant run

Comment: @the_lotus the compression process with ffmpeg.exe can't run like on flvconvert project, sir. so when i click on picturebox3, the process can't start. in flvconvert project, just 1 file to add and convert to mp3. may you try the source code first.

hope you understand, and sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: What we are saying is put a break point (or log) and look at the value inside cmd. Then run that string to see if it actually works. If it doesn't, than you'll easily know where the problem is.